# Turn this discord bot piece of code more simple

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**I'm struggling to get this code more simple but Python is case-sensitive a lot. Is there to turn this code cleaner????**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'Marcelo' in msg.content:
        print('Keyword found in message')
        await msg.channel.send("oh this shit again!")
    if 'marcelo' in msg.content:
        print('Keyword found in message')
        await msg.channel.send("oh this shit again!")
    if 'MARCELO' in msg.content:
        print('Keyword found in message')
        await msg.channel.send("oh this shit again!")
```

Comment: And please don't shout in your questions, we can hear you well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<str>.lower`, like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'marcelo' in msg.content.lower():
        print('Keyword found in message')
```

You also might not want to use the `in` keyword, as it means if you typed 'Hey Marcello', it would still output. I don't know if this is what you want, given the print statement, but most of the time it would make more sense to use `msg.content.lower().startsWith('marcelo')`, or `msg.content.lower() == 'marcelo'`